# CMake system include search path

Tags: cmake

I'm wondering how I would go about adding an include directory to the system search path for a CMake project. Particularly, I've some source that I'm trying to build a CMake project for.

The source is not mine, and so I don't really want to modify it.

The source has the following include directive:

```
#include <foo/bar.h>
```

So I need to add the directory containing foo to my search path. Is this something I can set within the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Useful links: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/help.html - http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use include_directories(..) to set directories that will be used for all targets, or add include directories only to a specific target with [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) or [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html):

```
set(foo_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/whatever)

set_property(TARGET YourTarget PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${foo_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_include_directories(<target> [SYSTEM] [BEFORE <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...]

#or
include_directories([AFTER|BEFORE] [SYSTEM] ${foo_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Thanks! I determined independently that include_directories directive does indeed work for angle bracket includes, and that I, in fact, had an error in my CMakeLists.txt file. Thanks for the info about the info about the specific target includes!